# How can I move the Shop Page Title to the left? (Woocommerce+Custom theme{minimog theme})

Tags: css, woocommerce

I’ve tried everything and it just won’t work.

This was my last attempt.. but it didn't move a pixel

```
@media screen and (min-width: 769px) {
.shop #fullscreen-header .featured-slide .entry-title {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 150px;
}
}
```

Could someone please, help me with that?

Our shop page using minimog is posher.com.br/shop

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use flex.

```
.heading {
  display: flex;
}
```

This is how it looks on my side.

[image]